# Load assemblies and views at runtime with net core 3 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

how are you?  I come to you for help.

I tell you I have an MVC web application developed in asp net core 3.

I have a base MVC web application, which contains areas and handles basic functionalities of a user management application, permissions, etc.

Now I want to add a new area for a specific functionality that in this case would be customer management. What I don't want is to add an area directly to the base project.

What I want is to dynamically load the dll files and the views, in order to keep the functionalities separate and that if one fails, the other continues to work.

Implement a functionality to load the DLLs, this does work because I tested it with web apis.

But I can't find the way to load the views of the areas, this I did some with MVC 5 Net Framework, try to pass the functionality and obviously the classes are not the same. You could help me with this.

**Thank you very much in advance.**

**Below the code:**

***PluginExtensions.cs***

```
public static class PluginExtensions
{

    public static IMvcBuilder AddExtensions(this IMvcBuilder mvc)
    {
        var serviceProvider = mvc.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var hostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Startup>();
        List<string> extensionDirectories = EnumerateExtensionDirectories(serviceProvider).ToList();
        List<string> searchPatternList = new List<string>
        {
            "*Extension.Mvc*.dll"
        };
        mvc.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
        {
            List<string> extensionAssemblies = new List<string>();
            foreach (var extensionDirectory in extensionDirectories)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < searchPatternList.Count; i++)
                {
                    List<string> tempList = EnumerateExtensionAssemblies(extensionDirectory, searchPatternList[i]).ToList();
                    if (tempList != null && tempList.Count > 0)
                        extensionAssemblies.AddRange(tempList);
                }//for(int i=0;i< searchPatternList.Count; i++)
            }//foreach (var extensionDirectory in extensionDirectories)
            foreach (var extensionAssembly in extensionAssemblies)
            {
                if (TryLoadExtensionAssembly(serviceProvider, extensionAssembly, out var assembly))
                {
                    //logger.Log(AbortAction.Layer.Infrastructure().Meta(new { extensionAssembly = new { extensionAssembly.FullName } }));
                    apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(assembly));
                }// if (TryLoadExtensionAssembly(serviceProvider, extensionAssembly, out var assembly))
            }// foreach (var extensionAssembly in extensionAssemblies)


        });

        if (hostingEnvironment.IsProduction() || hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            ConfigureAssemblyResolve(serviceProvider);
        }
        return mvc;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateExtensionAssemblies(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var hostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

        var extRootPath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, configuration["Extensibility:Ext"]);
        if (!Directory.Exists(extRootPath)) return new List<string>();
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(extRootPath, "*Extension.Mvc*.dll");
    }
    private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateExtensionAssemblies(string assembliesDirectory, string searchPattern)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(assembliesDirectory)) return new List<string>();
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(assembliesDirectory, searchPattern);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateExtensionDirectories(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var hostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

        var extRootPath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, configuration["Extensibility:Ext"]);
        if (!Directory.Exists(extRootPath)) return new List<string>();
        return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(extRootPath);
    }
    private static bool TryLoadExtensionAssembly(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, string extensionAssembly, out Assembly assembly)
    {

        //extensionAssembly
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(extensionAssembly))
            {
                assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(extensionAssembly);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Infrastructure().Routine(nameof(TryLoadExtensionAssembly)).Faulted(), ex);
        }

        assembly = default;
        return false;
    }
    private static void ConfigureAssemblyResolve(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var hostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Startup>();
        List<string> extensionDirectories = EnumerateExtensionDirectories(serviceProvider).ToList();
        List<string> extensionAssemblies = new List<string>();
        List<string> searchPatternList = new List<string>
        {
            "*Extension.Entities*.dll",
            "*Extension.Libs*.dll",
            "*Extension.Data*.dll",
            "*Extension.Application*.dll",
            "*Extension.UtilsConnectors*.dll"
        };
        foreach (var extensionDirectory in extensionDirectories)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < searchPatternList.Count; i++)
            {
                List<string> assembliesReferenceList = EnumerateExtensionAssemblies(extensionDirectory, searchPatternList[i]).ToList();
                if (assembliesReferenceList != null && assembliesReferenceList.Count > 0)
                    foreach (var assemblyReference in assembliesReferenceList)
                    {
                        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
                        {
                            return
                                File.Exists(assemblyReference)
                                    ? Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyReference)
                                    : null;
                        };// AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
                    }//foreach (var assemblyReference in assembliesReferenceList)
            }// for (int i = 0; i < searchPatternList.Count; i++)
        }//foreach (var extensionDirectory in extensionDirectories)
    }
}
public static class HostingEnvironmentExtensions
{
    public static bool IsDevelopmentExt(this IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        return hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment("DevelopmentExt");
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new SessionExpireAttribute());
        }).AddExtensions();
        ...
    }
```

**As you can see with this I load the dll files, this works.**

Later I copy the files (dll and views (html)) to the areas folder of my base project

[image]

**DLLs in my area**

[image]

**Finally views of my area**

[image]

**The result**

[image]

**Finally in the startup.cs file of the project type extension.**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
       ... 
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
           name: "AreaMyArea",
           areaName: "MyArea",
           pattern: "MyArea/{controller=MYHome}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "defaultMA",
              pattern: "{controller=MyExtHome}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
    }
```

**Sorry for the extensiveness of this information. Can you help me?. I tried to be as clear as possible. Thank you very much and have a great day.**

Comment: I am not I understand why do you want to load this dynamically?  You say " in order to keep the functionalities separate and that if one fails, the other continues to work" ...... BUT just because one view fails the whole website is not going to fail regardless of how you loaded the dlls.... Can you elaborate on why do you want to this.  You can just put views and controllers etc in separate projects and just reference those projects without having to load them dynamically. I do it all the time.. Every single MVC or Web API I create with .NET Core have the controllers in separate project.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but precisely what I want to avoid is making direct reference from the base project. This gives me the freedom to maintain functionalities, business logic, databases, etc., separately. This gives you the advantage (at least for me) of being able to plug or unplug functionality, without the need to open the base project and remove the references, recompile and republish. The way I put it is that if an error occurs in my plugin area, I correct that error and publish only that part. Thus the publications are lighter and more efficient (at least for me).

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156649/asp-net-core-register-controller-at-runtime