# Add assembly controller and view at runtime after start project ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, runtime, razor-pages

I want load assemblies at runtime, not Startup ( after start application ).
For this, I searched many solutions over the Internet and StackOverflow.
I found this answer at [ASP.Net Core register Controller at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156649/asp-net-core-register-controller-at-runtime/47629660#47629660)

cnxiaoby said: Create ActionDescriptor and register that in a startup.
Then anywhere you can use `_partManager.ApplicationParts.Add(assembly);`
Everything is fine, but I can just add Controller classes at runtime, If I want to add Razor views at runtime after start application, I get ["Not Found View Index"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh6hj.png)

Add views by this code:

```
var newView = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(data.FullName);
var viewAssembly = new CompiledRazorAssemblyPart(newView);
_partManager.ApplicationParts.Add(viewAssembly);
```

Add Controllers by this code:

```
var targetAssembly = new AssemblyPart(assembly);
_partManager.ApplicationParts.Add(targetAssembly);
```

After that, I set Custom Action Descriptor to this:

```
MyActionDescriptorChangeProvider.Instance.TokenSource.Cancel();
```

**Edit:**
That code was in HomeController.cs and SampleAction
If I put all codes inside HomeController.cs and Index"Action", Everything is fine.
If move code to other actions ( After application run and start run other action ), Code not work and I see that error.

1. What did I forget?
2. Why Code in First Action of project is fine, but not for others?
3. What is the difference between the first action and the rest?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to make it work? I am experience same problem and would like to know if you found solution

Comment: not yet exactly