# asp.net core: how to late-upload a Module Assembly, containing an dependency injectable Controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Considering how hard ASP.NET Core is making this, I'm open to being told I'm going about this the wrong way.

#### Objective

The objective is to be able to permit end users to upload Modules package (eg: nuget package,zip, etc.) containing API Controllers.

#### Great Lead

The following has great advice on using `IActionDescriptorChangeProvider` to permit adding Controllers later:

- [ASP.Net Core register Controller at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156649/asp-net-core-register-controller-at-runtime)

#### Works (almost)

Based on the above advice, had some partial success...

#### Works somewhat in the Default AssemblyLoadContext

When loading an external Module into the *Default* `AssemblyLoadContext`:

- Module's `ExampleM1Controller` (without constructor dependencies) is accessible (impressed!)
- Module's `ExampleM2Controller` (with a dependency on a `IExampleHService` previously registered in `IServiceCollection` at startup) works (*highly* impressed!).
- Module's `ExampleM3Controller` (with a dependency on a `IExampleMService`defined in the Module, and therefore not registered at Startup/known to `IServiceCollection`) raises an exception it can't instantiate `IExampleMService`.

#### Doesn't work much in a Custom AssemblyLoadContext

Beyond the small issue noted above, the situation is actually a little bit worse...

Because it was uploaded into the *Default* `AssemblyLoadContext`, the module can't be unloaded/replaced (starting/stopping the app would be highly disruptive to other users).

If I change the above to load into a *Custom* `AssemblyLoadContext` and try again this time:

- `ExampleM1Controller` (without dependencies) is accessible
- `ExampleM2Controller` (with a dependency on a service defined in Host) raises an exception it can't instantiate the `IExampleMService`
  `FIXED: SEE EDIT BELOW REGARDING 'PRIVATE' FLAG...`
- `ExampleM3Controller` (with a dependency on a service defined in Modules) raises an exception it can't instantiate the `IExampleHService`

So...that's turned out to be useless when the tires are kicked :-(

#### ServiceCollection is all locked up

So then went back to see if that Startup sequence couldn't be squeezed into delivering more functionality:

```cs
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            //Add a service
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IExampleSharedService, ExampleSharedService>();
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // Wire up custom Resetter invoked by upload controller.
            AddActionDescriptorChangeProvider(builder);
            //That was the last chance to add anthing before Build is called:
            var app = builder.Build();
            //Works, no problem:
            var x1 = app.Services.GetService<IExampleSharedService>();
            // Adding additional Services after the build event:
            // Will raise Exception
            // Not fixable by setting the flag by refletion, as it's too late.
            //builder.Services.GetType()
            //    .GetProperties(
            //    BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.SetProperty|BindingFlags.Instance
            //    )
            //    .Where(x => x.Name == "IsReadOnly")
            //    .First()
            //    .SetValue(builder.Services, false);
            // Without using reflection to re-permit adding services without raising
            // Exception "Cannot modify ServiceCollection after application is built."
            // it's still too late (Host already built, so no longer looking at source info)
            //builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILateService, LateService>();
            // Calling build twice also raises an exception:
            // builder.Build();
            // So...if we load a new DLL into a new AppDomainLoadContext,
            // that contains a Controller
            // that has a dependency on a Service, 
            // how do we teach the DI (IServiceProvider) how to build
            // it, and dependency service first???
            
            // Returns null.
            // ie: Unable to register late Controller or Module defined service:
            var x2 = app.Services.GetService<ILateService>();
```

#### A Module Load Event - But how can it be put to use?

Some examples regarding Plugins do exist on the net reference and discuss catching an event when an assembly is loaded, iterating over the Types in the Assembly that match an interface (eg: `ICalculator`), and instantiating them.
But...

a) It's the other way around (we're trying to inject into the domain descriptors about services that already exist in the `Host`)
b) even if we caught the event to teach the app's `IServiceCollection` about old and new services...it's locked as per above.

#### Impossible/Wrong way?

So, the fact

- that ASP.NET Core framework is really designed to lock in services at startup,
- doesn't seem to have a mechanism to late register them
- combined with a funny feeling that security -- even if ONLY giving Modules access to very specific Application Layer (ie, API) services -- might not be that hot...

...makes me hesitate and wonder whether I'm going about this all wrong.

- Yet...isn't there a single website out there that caters for end users to upload new modules to make an ecosystem, no? Not one? Really? Can this kind of thing only be done with a scripted language (eg: PHP), where files trigger an instant update?
- Or does the website HAVE to be reset to repass 'Go' and build up the `IServiceCollection` then `IServiceProvider`. (And that kind of disruption requires the uploaded modules only being loaded into memory at some deferred time -- eg midnight?)
- THAT sounds SO naff, just hard to believe that would be a recommended approach.
- Or is it that Modules are kept separate. and client side javascript is used to inject in ux modules at the right place on a page, that call back to their own services, hosted on their own servers, which in turn invoke Host APIs behind the scenes...?

#### Thanks

Thanks for any and all input leading to making SPA capable webpages+APIs+SPA modular.

#### Edit

Doesn't solve everything, but I missed something crucial!

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support

One MUST not forget to mark the source/shared assembly as `Private`.
Once that was changed, the second example started working, as it was ensured that the Controller's Constructor recognised the `IExampleHService` as being the one defined in the Host assembly -- and not something to look for in the Module directory.
Whew. With that solved, only one condition to go -- the third example, trying to resolve a Service that is unknown at Startup - but the `IServiceCollection` is no longer taking changes.

I think @davidfowl is onto something, and it's time to investigate taking over the controller creator. My current idea is so...yuck...I hesitate to write it down here. But first thoughts on it involves

a) importing the Module
b) Using Autofac to create a new scope
c) iterating over its Types for valid Interface/Instance types to register in the scope
d) Save the scope, associated to the imported Assembly, in a singleton dictionary (!)
e) Use a Controller Factory, that uses the Controller Type's Assembly to find the right child scope again, to use it when instantiating the controller....
f) Hope?
It's messy as...but if one can't update the root container...worth giving it a shot and reporting back if it worked at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156649/asp-net-core-register-controller-at-runtime?

Comment: Yes! That was a great article (I referenced it at the top of my question). 
The only issue remaining is that the example in the above post doesn't bring across the dependencies so that Constructors can be DI'ed. :-(

Comment: I think this is a great analysis. ASP.NET Core does *not* make this easy and you'd need to build something custom using some of the same building blocks to make it work. The DI container is immutable after startup by design so that is a challenge if you have dynamically loaded controllers with new dependencies that need to be added. You can use a custom controller activator to control that maybe but you can't add new dependencies to the container.

Comment: Thanks @davidfowl - as per my edit of the post, you may be onto something, that I have to investigate further. 
Now that ExampleM2Controller is working ... I'm persisting just to see if can be done - but I'm also more fully aware that I won't be able to limit what Host Services are available to the Module Controller. Everything...That's quite a lot/too much power to third party module writers. So after this, I'll need to come up with a different route to offering (safe) modular flexibility...

Comment: Here's some code for dynamic loading of MVC modules I wrote a while back: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/d16c352c19b89acc2a20fe4c1061cad9. It doesn't attempt to solve the dynamic dependency problem though, you would need to have another container with dependencies that would fallback to the original container for ones it didn't know about (https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/blob/242115849b741325b667050b40b78d947ea477f0/src/OrchardCore/OrchardCore/Shell/Builders/Extensions/ServiceProviderExtensions.cs)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for sharing! Your project was one of the ones that popped up on my radar to investigate as to how others were approaching the problem. So that's extra cool! :-)
In the meantime, sharing where I got up to here:
https://github.com/skysgh/Spike.AspNetCore.ModuleLoading.AssemblyLoadContext/ 
I'll pause a sec to do some further research on the matter and then come back to give it another shot...

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Your suggestion to look at how controllers are activated was just the trick. I've just checked into the above repo a (very messy/thrashy/crap...but works!) update that shows one can keep track of the child scopes created, and recall them when later creating controllers that can inject singleton services developed in the child scopes when the plugin is loaded. Utter crap coding, but that can all be worked out later. For now. ..it's good to simply know that Plugins *can* be loaded with DI working. 
As for Security: Microsoft clearly says that it's not in that business.

Comment: And now...the important part...how to do assign the very well deserved glory to you as you only wrote a Comment, not an Answer? :-)